# Does the statement "$f = 0$ almost everywhere" depend on the measure that is defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I know the convention is to use the Lebesgue measure but is there ever a situation where we would interpret "$f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere" by using a different measure?

For example, let $f(x) = 1$. Then $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere with respect to the trivial measure defined by $\mu(E) = 0$ for all $E$. Of course, I say this is because $\mu(\{x : f(x) \neq 0\}) = 0$.

The reason I ask is because of this theorem:

> Show that if $\mu$ is a finite measure and $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, then $f_n \to f$ in measure.

How should I interpret $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere?

Thank you.

Comment: The "almost everywhere" there refers to $\mu$. So there's a set $N$ with $\mu(N) = 0$ such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$ in the complement of $N$.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: The term "almost everywhere" is referring to Lebesgue measure almost everywhere.

Comment: The "in measure" also refers to measure $\mu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "almost everywhere" always refers to the measure under consideration.

And if several measures are under consideration, it should be specified to which one refers, usually by prefixing "$\nu$-almost everywhere". [If all measures under consideration have exactly the same null sets, that can be omitted without causing ambiguity, but it's not necessarily advisable to do that even then.]

So here, the "almost everywhere" refers to $\mu$, there is a $\mu$-measurable set $N$ with $\mu(N) = 0$ such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ holds for all $x$ in the complement of $N$.